# General form for the integral of $ab\over c$

Tags: integration

Given $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $c(x)$, assuming I know the first derivatives and integrals of each, is there a general form for $\int {ab\over c} dx$?

Comment: What do you mean by a "general form" for $\int \frac{a(x)b(x)}{c(x)}\,dx$?

Comment: @MarkViola I mean an answer that contains derivatives, base forms, and integrals for a,b, and c. e.g. $a\deriv {b}$+\int c dx$

Comment: No. It strongly depends on the functions $a,b,c$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier what if I know the derivatives and integrations for each function?

Comment: If you know that then you can probably *compute* $\int \frac{ab}{c}dx$, but there is no simple function $F$ such that $\int \frac{ab}{c}dx=F(a',b',c',\int a,\int b,\int c)$ for any $a,b,c$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I’m unfamiliar with the notation used in your last term

Comment: There is no general form as far as I'm aware. But there are general Technics for certain situations (For instance when the functions are polynomials)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general there is no simple function that will give out an antiderivative of $\frac{ab}{c}$ in terms of the derivatives and anti-derivatives of $a$, $b$, $c$.

As an example, it is well-known that there is no closed form for the anti-derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ (related to the Normal density).

Yet away from $0$ this function can be written $$f(x)=\frac{a(x)b(x)}{c(x)}$$
where $$\cases{a(x)=xe^{-x^2}\\b(x)=1\\c(x)=x}$$
and all the derivatives and anti-derivatives of $a,b,c$ have closed forms.